# How to change a space between lines in PurePDF?

Tags: actionscript-3, pdf, actionscript, pdf-generation

I want to change a space between lines in document with PurePDF but i cannot find a way to do it. I used Chunk and Paragraph for output text but they haven't any properties to change space between lines. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\n` will do. For example

```
        var title:Paragraph = new Paragraph("Purchase Order Summary\n\n");          
        title.alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        document.add(title);
```